# Partial Form Submission in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my Spring application, I have to provide Save as Draft functionality. But I am not able to do partial form submission because of entity validation rules. I want to validate the form only when Save Final button is clicked not when Save Draft button is clicked. I have tried removing @Valid annotation but still getting  javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException error.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/saveSalesDetails")
public String saveSales(Sales sales, @RequestParam("action") String formAction, BindingResult result, Model model) {     

    if(formAction.equalsIgnoreCase("Save Draft")) {

    }
    else if (formAction.equalsIgnoreCase("Save Final") {

    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [mip.salesproj.model.Sales] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Target Of Sale should be between 5-20 characters', propertyPath=targetSale, rootBeanClass=class mip.salesproj.model.Sales, messageTemplate='Target Of Sale should be between 5-20 characters'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Target Of Sale field should not be blank', propertyPath=targetSale, rootBeanClass=class mip.salesproj.model.Sales, messageTemplate='Target Of Sale field should not be blank'} 
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you would have read the stack trace you would see that validation isn't coming from the web layer, but from storing it. Validation integrates with JPA (or rather hibernate) directly to prevent you from storing invalid entities. So you would need to disable it for JPA as well (although do you really want to do that?). Also your controller is wrong the `BindingResult` MUST directly follow the model attribute (`Sales` in this case) else it won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum  yes the BindingResult must directly follow the model attribute, it was a typo actually. But the point is how do I achieve the partial form submission? I thought I would use two controllers, one for Save Draft and one for final submission. In the final submission controller I would use Valid.

Comment: Please read my comment. As mentioned the error isn't coming from the web validation but rather from the persistence layer which integrates with Bean Validation automatically.

Comment: @M. Deinum  I have read your comment and understood it. My question is how do I go about solving this issue? I have already explained what I tried.

Comment: As stated the issue is with persisting the entity NOT receiving the form submit. So trying to solve it on the web layer is obviously not going to help. I'm not sure if you can disable validation for an entity when persisting only in a certain use case.